# 3rd party Authentication Issues in Google Appscript

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, gsuite-addons

I am using an internal service to Authenticate my Gsuite add-on. The Issue is we cannot find any request made from the Add-on to internal servers on Prod (or Dev environments). These are public facing authentication endpoints.

Currently this Addon only runs in Gmail. Unsure If there are any bandwidth limits we might be reaching but Google support said they couldn't help.

We followed the docs [Google provides](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services) for 3rd Part Oauth.

auth File:

```js
function accessProtectedResource(url, method_opt, headers_opt, body) {

  var service = getOAuthService();
  var maybeAuthorized = service.hasAccess();
  if (maybeAuthorized) {
    // A token is present, but it may be expired or invalid. Make a
    // request and check the response code to be sure.

    // Make the UrlFetch request and return the result.
    var accessToken = service.getAccessToken();
    var method = method_opt || 'get';
    var headers = headers_opt || {};
    headers['Authorization'] = Utilities.formatString('Bearer %s', accessToken);

    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'headers': headers,
      'method' : method,
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'muteHttpExceptions': true, // Prevents thrown HTTP exceptions.
      'payload': JSON.stringify(body)
    });

    var code = resp.getResponseCode();
    if (code >= 200 && code < 300) {
      return resp.getContentText('utf-8'); // Success
    } else if (code >= 400 && code <= 403) {
       // Not fully authorized for this action.
       maybeAuthorized = false;
    } else {
       // Handle other response codes by logging them and throwing an exception.
       Logger.log('Server error (%s): %s', code.toString(),
                     resp.getContentText('utf-8'));

       throw ('Backend server error: ' + code);
    }
  }

  if (!maybeAuthorized) {
    // Invoke the authorization flow using the default authorization
    // prompt card.
    CardService.newAuthorizationException()
        .setAuthorizationUrl(service.getAuthorizationUrl())
        .setCustomUiCallback('createCompanyeAuthorizationUi')
        .setResourceDisplayName('Company')
        .throwException();


  }
}

function getOAuthService() {
  // added Console.log for debug
  var service = OAuth2.createService('COMPANY_AUTH')
  var servicewithurl = service.setAuthorizationBaseUrl(urlBase + '/oauth2/authenticate/');
  var setauthBase = servicewithurl.setAuthorizationBaseUrl(urlBase + '/oauth2/authenticate/');
  console.log('setauthBase ', setauthBase);
  var setToken = setauthBase.setTokenUrl(urlBase + '/oauth/token/');
console.log('setToken ',setToken);
  var setCallback = setToken.setCallbackFunction('authCallback');
      console.log('setCallback ', setCallback);
  setCallback.setClientId('2222TW9LzuT4AgAMN')
      .setClientSecret('WZN5tyDKfMYoDLNnC')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())

console.log('setCallback2 ', setCallback);
  return setCallback;
}

function authCallback(callbackRequest) {
  var authorized = getOAuthService().handleCallback(callbackRequest);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      'Success! <script>setTimeout(function() { top.window.close() }, 1);</script>');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied');
  }
}


function createCompanyAuthorizationUi() {

  var service = getOAuthService();
  var authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
  var authAction = CardService.newAuthorizationAction().setAuthorizationUrl(authUrl);

  var CompanyLogo = CardService.newImage().setAltText("Company Logo").setImageUrl("image_url_replaced");
  var headerText = 'Create actions in Company from your email.';
  var mainImage = CardService.newImage().setAltText("Company Mail").setImageUrl("image_url_replaced");
  var loginButton = CardService.newImage().setAltText("Login").setImageUrl("image_url_replaced").setAuthorizationAction(authAction);  
  var signupLink = CardService.newOpenLink()
        .setUrl(urlBase + "/join")
        .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.FULL_SIZE)
        .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.NOTHING);
  var signupButton = CardService.newImage().setAltText("Sign up").setImageUrl("image_url_replaced").setOpenLink(signupLink);

  var featureOne = CardService.newKeyValue()
    .setIconUrl("image_url_replaced")
    .setContent("Company is the best way to plan, execute, and monitor all of your teams's projects in one place.")
  .setMultiline(true);  

  var featureTwo = CardService.newKeyValue()
    .setIconUrl("image_url_replaced")
    .setContent("Content here")
  .setMultiline(true);

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
          .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph())
          .addWidget(CompanyLogo)
          .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(headerText))
          .addWidget(mainImage)
          .addWidget(signupButton)
          .addWidget(loginButton)
          .addWidget(featureOne)
          .addWidget(featureTwo)
      ).build();
  return [card];
}
function resetOAuth() {
  getOAuthService().reset();
}


function getCompanyResourceUrls() {
  accessProtectedResource(urlBase + '/api/v1/books/');
}

function makeRequest(url, params) {
  var oauthService = getOAuthService();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + oauthService.getAccessToken()
    },
    body: params
  });
  return response;
}

function getUserId() {
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var userId = cache.get('userId');

  if(userId) {
    return userId;
  }

  var response = accessProtectedResource(urlBase + '/oauth/getIdentity');
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  var userId = data.data.id;

  cache.put('userId', userId);

  return userId;
}
```

appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
      "libraryId": "",
      "version": "37",
      "developmentMode": true
    }]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": ["https://company.com/", "https://company.com/oauth/token/", "https://company.com/api/v1/books/", "https://companycom/oauth/revoke"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Name",
    "logoUrl": "https://logourl.com",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
    }],
    "universalActions": [{
      "text": "Logout",
      "runFunction": "logout"
    }],
    "primaryColor": "#ffffff",
    "secondaryColor": "#ffffff",
    "authorizationCheckFunction": "getCompanyResourceUrls",
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": ["https://company.com/"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake:

```
.setCustomUiCallback('createCompanyeAuthorizationUi')
```

but you have

```
createCompanyAuthorizationUi
```

I am not sure, but it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and great catch! This was a typo when I was trying to censor out the company name, there isn't a typo in prod.